# How to bypass certificate errors using Microsoft Edge

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, microsoft-edge, self-signed, self-signed-certificate

When attempting to access the local git server page Microsoft Edge displays a certificate error because the git server is using a self-signed certificate.  I would like to enable access to this specific web host and bypass the error message. This can be done in other browsers, but apparently Edge doesn't provide a way to override certificate handling or make exceptions.

Error message:

> This site is not secure.  DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Just type the letters: `thisisunsafe`.

Just click anywhere on the tab to give it focus (no button), and type the letters.  (The letters will not be visible or show up in a field or anything.)  After completing the words, the website loads, but will show as 'insecure' in the left of the address bar.

Edge will mark the website as "allowed", unless this operation is done in an inPrivate window. After it's saved, it works even with inPrivate.

Comment: Wow, I was very skeptical but I just typed that on the cert error page and it reloaded the page!

Comment: This should be accepted answer, as we are reaching Internet Explorer sunset in middle of 2022, so Edge is only available browser for developers testing with self-signed certs

Comment: For what it's worth, this also appears to work in Chrome (tested on version 
Version 100.0.4896.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)); so it's probably upstream from Chromium and may work on any Chrome-based browser.

Comment: Just tried it and it loaded the page! To be clear, you must type with the focus on the page, *not* on the address bar (which would do a web search). Also, to have it saved, this must not be done in inPrivate window.

Comment: Didn't expect it to work because it looks like a game cheating code but it actually works:)  Just remember don't input in the address textinput area, click anywhere in the web page will do the trick, after typed the string the page will be reloaded automatically.

Comment: Edge 119 version: It works only for the current session - which is not very useful, and it warns again if you close and re-open the browser.

Answer (score 55):

## As of v119 and later, the flag you want is `WebTransport Developer Mode`

Old answer:

If you're trying to reach a page served from localhost that has a self signed cert, you can enable a flag in edge.  Go to `edge://flags` and search for `localhost`, and enable the flag `Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost.`

[image]

Comment: This worked a treat. The thisisunsafe solution did not, likely because edge is being managed by organisation

Comment: What to do if it is not on localhost, but a page with selfsigned cert on local network and I am forced to use Edge on Linux? 
Does it mean that the internal webpage must be exposed to public net?

Comment: On 119 version there isn't such a flag anymore.

Answer (score 11):

Microsoft EDGE does not directly have a way to manage certificates or import certificates in order to avoid certificate errors.  To allow a self-signed certificate to be used by Microsoft-Edge it is necessary to use the "certmgr.msc" tool from the command line to import the certificate as a Trusted Certificate Authority.

This can be done as follows:

- Click on the red certificate error message to view the failing certificate
- Click on View Certificate
- Click on Export to File (any location, foo.crt)
- Start a cmd shell and type the command "certmgr.msc" to open the certificate wizard
- From the menu bar select "Action" > "All Tasks" > "Import..."
- A popup window will appear asking for the "Store Location"  Select Current User or Local Machine.  Click Next.
- A new popup window will appear asking for the File Name:  Browse and select your exported certificate file, foo.crt and Click Open.
- The popup should now display the full path to your certificate file, foo.crt.  Click Next.
- A new popup window will appear asking you to allow Windows to choose the "certificate Store" based on the certificate, or allow you to specify the certificate store manually.  Select manual option, "Trusted Root Certificate Authority".  Click Next.
- A final popup will appear "Completing the Certificate Import Wizard".  Review the settings and Click Finish.
- You should get a "import successful" message.
- Close the import wizard application and try the URL again in the EDGE browser.  If this worked you will not get the certificate error and the page will load normally

Comment: For me, those instructions worked however not by importing the certificate itself, but the certification authority that created the certificate instead.

Comment: If you are running Edge on Linux see @MartyNeal answer below.

Comment: FWIW: As at this date, we have the Enterprise CA's certificate chain installed in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store on all of our workstations. Consequently, Internet Explorer (11) happily accepts any site that is secured with an SSL certificate that has been issued by our ECA; MS-Edge however, running on the exact same computer, does not accept/recognize any of them...

Comment: I had to first select the "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities" in the left pane in certmgr, otherwise "Action" > "All Tasks" > "Import..." was not available.

Comment: Edge 119 version: no "View Certificate" albeit you can view it's text, and no"Export to File" available.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible that IT policy (group policy or registry) is affecting this behaviour.

These were tested in Windows 10:

### Check group policy

1. from the start menu, search "group policy" and open the entry with the subtitle "Control Panel"
2. Navigate to `Administrative Templates` > `Windows Components` > `Microsoft Edge`
3. Check that `Prevent certificate error overrides` is Not configured, or disabled

### Check registry

1. from the start menu, type "regedit" and open the app
2. Paste this into the search bar (or navigate to) `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge`
3. Delete the DWORD `SSLErrorOverrideAllowed`, or set it to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this error in Microsoft Edge Version 119.0.2151.72 by typing edge://flags in the address bar and then enabling WebTransport Developer Mode Flag.

Answer (score 1):

Load the self-signed certificate into the Enterprise Trust using cert managed. Edge will then trust it.

Comment: I've been struggling with this forever with intranet IIS sites signed with mkcert.  Adding the CA cert to Trusted Root Certificate Authority did not work.  Adding it to Enterprise Trust was the trick!!  Now I'll try to update it on GP.  Thank you!